# CSS word-wrap property does't support word which having any special characters

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n7b5dxyd/6/)

Am trying to achive word wrapping depends on space given within a fixed `div` it comes perfectly if we use normal text characters as word. If a word has any special characters it takes it as an space.. Check this fiddle(attached above) for demo.
For example :- Actually I want is this

```
AAAA%%%%AAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
A AA-aa&amb;adsd !212sad
```

But the Output is

```
AAAA%%%%
AAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA A AA-
aa&amb;adsd !212sad
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="diva">
    AAAA%%%%AAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA A AA-aa&amb;adsd !212sad
</div>

CSS
.diva {
    width:100px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
}
```

is there any restriction why it is happening?

Comment: Does `word-wrap:normal;` get the behavior you want?

Comment: Nope even the word take space for `-` character

Comment: This is works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/johannesMt/f25zryrc/2/